# Why does a program work on one computer and not another when both have the same virtual env ? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, virtualenv, streamlit, virtual-environment

I am very confused as to why this is happening : I have a python program, to run this program I provide an enviromment to the users. I was under the belief that with the same python version, and the same python env, a python code would run identically on two computers.

When a coworker of mine tried running it, after installing my enviroment, he was met with this error :

**ModuleFoundError : No module named Blinker**

[image]

But other coworkers of mine have tried running my code, with no such error.
I have now added blinker to my list of requirements for my enviroment, and it runs correctly.

The list of requirements in question :

```
altair==4.2.0
attrs==21.4.0
blinker==1.4
matplotlib==3.4.3
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
numpy==1.20.3
numpydoc==1.1.0
openpyxl==3.0.9
pandas==1.3.4
pandocfilters==1.5.0
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter==3.0.1
streamlit==1.0.0
Flask==2.0.2
protobuf==3.19.4
Django==3.2.8
scipy==1.7.1
```

Why is this happening?

more info : - I provide a folder with the list of requirements, and a .bat that installs the venv on their computers w modules from the list.
- The users install the venv, then in the run.bat of my program, I specify to use my venv.

Comment: Can you post the error as text?

Comment: What OS are you running on, what OS is he?

Comment: yes the error is  ModuleFoundError : No module named Blinker

Comment: we are both on windows and using Python 3.7

Comment: When you say you were running on the same venv - what do you mean by that?
You output requirements and he built the venv from those?

Comment: Yes, I provide a folder containing : - the list of requirements  - an .bat that builds the env from that list, and in the run.bat of my program i explicitly state which env to use (i will add this to the post)